# What is the default timeout for a request when using a single-threaded Flask application

Tags: flask

I'm not able to find/determine what is the default timeout value in seconds for a request in a Flask Application when *threaded* is set as *False*.

I made multiple concurrent request to the server which completes the task in about 50 seconds, so meanwhile, the other requests keep on waiting. Now, I want to determine after how much time the request timeout.

I manually set-up a server and tested for 100 seconds, I read the documentation but I didn't find the value.

What I was able to find was if I'm using Gunicorn, I can set a parameter *keep_live* to whatever value I want. But I want to know without Gunicorn i.e.,  using Flask development server, what is the default value?